# Is there a way to create sparkline based on the data on an existing excel sheet?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl, pandas.excelwriter

I have an excel sheet which contains some data, now I want to create sparkline based on this existing data and output the sparkline on the same excel sheet, is there a way to do it?
The below approach did  not work

```
worksheet=openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
worksheet.add_sparkline('d1',{'range':'Sheet1!a1:c1'})
```

file.xlsx is an existing excel file, there are some data in cell a1, b1 and c1, and I want to create the sparkline in cell d1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a couple of months old, but since there are no answers:

You are loading a work*book* and then trying to interact with a work*sheet*. To load the worksheet in openpyxl, you can use something like:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
ws = wb.worksheets[0] # ws is the first worksheet in wb
```

or

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet'] # ws is specified by title
```

I can't find the `add_sparkline` function in openpyxl. However there is one in the xlsxwriter package that behaves in this same way. Perhaps that was what you were looking for?

It's always useful to post the error feedback in your terminal too, for faster troubleshooting. :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts which is gladly appreciated. I need to create sparkline as well as append tabs to an existing excel workbooks, excelwriter would only have the capability to add/writer but not read and modify, so openpyxl is the only way. After I did more research, I learned openpyxl does not support sparkline, so the I think the answer to my own post is “No”.

Comment: You could perhaps use both openpyxl and xlsxwriter. It may have to involve saving a temporary copy of a workbook as a local file and then opening it in the second package, but I do that for cases involving images that are unsupported by openpyxl.